# Ajax call onSubmit not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onsubmit

I have a log-in form. Before do the log-in I would like to make sure that username and password are true.. I am trying to achieve this with ajax, but so far it is not working..

in my form I am calling the function check_user onSubmit.
This is my code.

**EDITED:**

```
    function check_user(){

            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();

            if(username.length>1 && password.length>1){ 
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "Something/check_user_exists.php",
                        data : {'username':username, 'password':password},
                        cache : false,
                        success : function(response) {
                            if (response == 1) {
                            alert ('true'); 
                            return true;                    
                            } else {
                            alert('false'); //this happens and goes to login.php       
                            $('#username').css('border', '2px red solid');
                            document.getElementById("username").placeholder = "Wrong username or password";
                            $('#password').css('border', '2px red solid');
                            document.getElementById("password").placeholder = "Wrong username or password";                     
                            return false;                   
                            }
                        }
                    });     
            }else{
                //when this happens it stays on the page
                $('#username').css('border', '2px red solid');
                document.getElementById("username").placeholder = "Wrong username or password";
                $('#password').css('border', '2px red solid');
                document.getElementById("password").placeholder = "Wrong username or password";
                return false;   
            }
        }
```

In my PHP file check_user_exists.php I have also this code:

```
$fp = fopen("debug.txt", "a") or die("Couldn't open log file for writing.");
        fwrite($fp, PHP_EOL ."inside");
        fflush($fp);
        fclose($fp);
```

**NEW:** The debug.txt file is created. But only when I use Chrome. With Firefox is not created, so I guess in Firefox the ajax is not working?

My form:

```
<form name="login_form" action="Something/login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check_user(this);">
```

Comment: add e.preventDefault();  to first line in function

Comment: If I do this it goes immediately to action="login.php"

Comment: dont use input type submit, use input type button and trigger your function check_user on .click() event listner of jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can open the chrome network debug to see if the ajax is being called.

[Debugging Asynchronous JavaScript with Chrome DevTools](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/)

Also on the following line, you might need a slash before the filename

```
url : "/check_user.php",
```

Comment: Actually I have "Something/check_user.php", but i tried  "/Something/check_user.php" and also  "./Something/check_user.php" and still not working

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
 data : 'username=' + username +"&password=" + password,
```

It would be

```
data : {username:username,password:password},
```

Comment: Nope - it would be `data: {username:username, password:password}`

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong format:

```
data : 'username=' + username +"&password=" + password,
```

it should be 
`data : {'username':username, 'password':password},`

add the `e.preventDefault();` at the first line in your function start

suggestion: in your chrome or other browser press `F12`, go to networks and see if the ajax request actually goes, if it goes then what is the response you get.

**Edited:**

You forgot to pass the reference of the form in the function parameter, that was the error, below is my working code:

```
<script>
 function check_user(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 alert('yes');
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        if(username.length>1 && password.length>1){
        e.preventDefault(); // I added this but still it is not working
        alert('alive'); // this is working          

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "check_user.php",
                    data : 'username=' + username +"&password=" + password,
                    cache : false,
                    success : function(response) {
                        if (response == 1) {
                        return true;                    
                        } else {        
                        $('#username').css('border', '2px red solid');
                        document.getElementById("username").placeholder = "Wrong username or password";
                        $('#password').css('border', '2px red solid');
                        document.getElementById("password").placeholder = "Wrong username or password";                     
                        return false;                   
                        }
                    }
                });     
        }else{
//this is working
            $('#username').css('border', '2px red solid');
            document.getElementById("username").placeholder = "Wrong username or password";
            $('#password').css('border', '2px red solid');
            document.getElementById("password").placeholder = "Wrong username or password";
            return false;   
        }
    }

</script>

<body>
<form name="login" id="contactForm" action="Something/login.php" method="post" onSubmit="return check_user(this);">
<input type = "submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this and it goes immediately to the action of the form -> login.php

Comment: are you sure that this function is being called on  `onSubmit` event of the form?

Comment: Yes,   <form name="login" id="contactForm" action="Something/login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check_user();">

Comment: check the edited part of my answer now the form will not submit

Comment: Ok as I see correctly, you have changed this: onsubmit="return check_user(this); You added "this" into the brackets. Now it's not working, but the behavior changed. Please check my modified question.. thx!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `e.preventDefault()` on your form action.

```
$("#formID").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    check_user();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and tell me what would be the error? if any!

```
;(function(){

function check_user(){
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    if(username != '' && password != ''){
         $.ajax({
              type : 'POST', // or the method 
              url: "check_user.php",
              data: $('form').serialize(),
              beforeSend: function( xhr ) {   
              },
              error: function(data){
                  //handle errors from server                                         
              },
              success : function(data){
                  //handle success data from server     
              }
            })
              .done(function( data ) {
                if ( console && console.log ) {
                   // handle anything else after Ajax finishes the request
                  //console.log( data );
                }
            }); 
    }else{
       // output validation error
       alert('please type username and password');
    }

  };

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried with
async: false,

Comment: Please post your doubts/questions under comment section of the question not in the answer section.